# how to remove CJuiDatePicker button using Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Below is my code. I'd like to know if there's a way to prevent the button to be visible as I only want the `textField` to show.

```
<?php
if ($model->fechaCierre1_f!='') 
$model->fechaCierre1_f=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($model->fechaCierre1_f));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
         'model'=>$model,
         'attribute'=>'fechaCierre1_f',
         'value'=>$model->fechaCierre1_f,
         'language' => 'es',
         'htmlOptions' => array('readonly'=>"", 'class' => 'span1'),
         'options'=> array(
    'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd', 
    'altFormat'=>'dd-mm-yy', 
    'changeMonth'=>'true', 
    'changeYear'=>'true', 
    'yearRange'=>'2012:2014', 
    'showOn'=>'both',
    'buttonText'=>'<i class="icon-calendar"></i>'
),)); ?>
```

Comment: Traduje tu pregunta para que reciba respuestas ya que SO es una pagina en ingles.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from the code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
     'model'=>$model,
     'attribute'=>'fechaCierre1_f',
     'value'=>$model->fechaCierre1_f,
     'language' => 'es',
     'htmlOptions' => array('readonly'=>"", 'class' => 'span1'),
     'options'=> array(
'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd', 
'altFormat'=>'dd-mm-yy', 
'changeMonth'=>'true', 
'changeYear'=>'true', 
'yearRange'=>'2012:2014', 
'showOn'=>'both',
'buttonText'=>'<i class="icon-calendar"></i>'
),));
```

Then replace it with the following

```
echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,fechaCierre1_f,'');
```

If you still have issues, though you may have already changed the date, possibly also try

```
echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,date('d-m-Y',strtotime($model->fechaCierre1_f)),'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove below 2 lines from your code, then the button will be removed.

```
    'showOn'=>'both',
    'buttonText'=>'<i class="icon-calendar"></i>'
```